# Gerador de função retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Considere a seguinte função:

```
function* gerador() {
    let foo = yield "a"
    let bar = yield "b"
    let baz = yield "c"

    return `${foo} ${bar} ${baz}`
}

let gen = gerador();
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
```

O output será o seguinte:

```
{ value: 'a', done: false }
{ value: 'b', done: false }
{ value: 'c', done: false }
{ value: 'undefined undefined undefined', done: true }
```

Repare que o último `console.log(gen.next());` retornou `undefined` para as variáveis `foo`, `bar` e `baz`.

O que não consigo entender é que a expressão `yield "a"` retorna o objeto `{ value: 'a', done: false }` mas a variável `foo` permanece `undefined` e para atribuir o valor, teria que passar como parâmetro o `value` no próximo método `next()`:

```
let gen = gerador();
let v1 = gen.next().value;
let v2 = gen.next(v1).value;
let v3 = gen.next(v2).value;
console.log(gen.next(v3));
```

Assim teria o resutado esperado:

```
{ value: 'a b c', done: true }
```

Comment: Pergunta interessante! `+1`

Answer (score 2):

O `yield` é como um `return` em funções geradoras, ou seja quando a função lê o `yield` dá devolve a expressão que está depois dele (as strings que tens) e pausa a execução da função.

Quando chamas de novo o `.next()` acontece a mesma coisa com o próximo `yeld`, retornando a próxima variável, etc. Quando o `yield` retorna a expressão que tem a seguir (na mesma linha) não deixa nada para o `let` e por isso eles vão ficando com valor `undefined`.

No final o ultimo `.next()` chama na verdade o `return` da função, pois chamaste 3 vezes o `.next()` e os `yield` já deram o seu retorno, antes do 4<sup>o</sup> `yield` a função ficou em pause depois de fazer o `yield` de "c", e então esse último `.next()` vai invocar o `return` da ultima linha.

Repara no exemplo em baixo onde coloquei `console.log(typeof foo, foo);` dentro da função e que confirma que as variáveis vão ficando `undefined`.

```js
function* gerador() {
    let foo = yield "a"
    let bar = yield "b"
    let baz = yield "c"
    
    console.log(typeof foo, foo); // repara que aqui dá undefined

    return `${foo} ${bar} ${baz}`
}

let gen = gerador();
console.log(gen.next()); // dá { value: 'a', done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // dá { value: 'b', done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // dá { value: 'c', done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // chama o return e dá { value: 'undefined undefined undefined', done: true }
```

Comment: "O yield é como um return" não sabia disso, agora faz sentido. Obrigado.